# Error 400 Unable to forward request due to: Stream closed

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, visualforce-component

I am trying to implement a drag and drop attachment component from a tutorial ( http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-drag-and-drop-file-uploader-component-with-progress-bar-html5-and-pure-javascript-based/ ) but I am running into an error "Error 400  Unable to forward request due to: Stream closed" ( please refer to screenshot). If you guys have any clue please let me know. Thank you all : )
[image]

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple fix. Just add your sandbox URL to a remote site settings and you should not see this error anymore. This is important because of the @RestResource being used in Apex Class which is a webservice call.

Comment: Here's the link on how to create [Remote Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_remote_site_settings.htm) in SalesForce

Comment: Thank you @Giene I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. However, that alone did not resolve the issue. I have added my sandbox URL and made sure our Org is API enable but none of those seem to be the solution unless I am missing something here.